Distributing 7 distinct chocolates to 7 people such that exactly 3 of them get none
Question:  Alex bought seven different chocolates.  If he has seven cousins, how many ways can he distribute the seven chocolates so that exactly three cousins get no chocolates ?

[TL;DR:- my main issue is with Case 3, so if you want to skip first
two cases its fine]

My attempt:
The seven chocolates can be given in the following cases to the cousins:
Case 1: 4,1,1,1
First we shall select the 4 cousins who would get the chocolates in ${7 \choose 4}$ ways
Then selecting which cousin out of the four will get 4 chocolates in ${4 \choose 1}$ ways
After that we shall select which 4 chocolates out of 7 shall be given to him in ${7 \choose 4}$ ways
Finally the rest 3 chocolates can be distributed among the 3 cousins in 3! ways
Case 2: 3, 2, 1, 1
First we shall select the 4 cousins who would get the chocolates in ${7 \choose 4}$ ways
Then selecting which cousin out of the four will get 3 chocolates in ${4 \choose 1}$ ways
After that we shall select which 3 chocolates out of 7 shall be given to him in ${7 \choose 3}$ ways
Then we shall select which cousin out of 3 will get 2 chocolates in ${3 \choose 1}$ ways
The 2 chocolates for him can be selected in ${4 \choose 2}$ ways
Finally the remaining 2 chocolates can be distributed among the 2 cousins in 2! ways

Case 3: 2, 2, 2, 1
First we shall select the 4 cousins who would get the chocolates in ${7 \choose 4}$ ways
Then selecting which cousin out of the four will get just one chocolate in ${4 \choose 1}$ ways
After that we shall select which particular chocolate would be given to him in ${7 \choose 1}$ ways
Now here my thought is to divide the 6 chocolates into 3 pairs and then distribute these 3 pairs to the 3 cousins in 3! ways, but I am not getting how to express it mathematically , will it be as ${6 \choose 2}$ * ${4 \choose 2}$  * 3! , but I believe this would be overcounting some cases while making the three pairs.  How shall I progress then ?
As per the author's solution the way he did was as follows:


For case 3, you are almost correct. Once you have given a chocolate to the cousin who gets only one, you give two to one of the remaining cousins in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways, to the next in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, and to the last in $\binom{2}{2} = 1$ way. So the total is $\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{7}{1}\cdot\binom{6}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{2} = 2520$.

First, I will focus on your approach, and how it can be corrected.  Then, at the end, I will explain the problem composer's equivalent approach.
Once you apply the factors of $~\displaystyle 4 \times \binom{7}{1},~$ you have left (in effect):

Person-A, Person-B, Person-C.

Chocolate-1, Chocolate-2, ... Chocolate-6.


There are $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{2}~$ ways of selecting which two chocolates go to Person-A.
Once that is done, there are then $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2}~$ ways of selecting which two chocolates go to Person-B.
Once that is done, there are then $~\displaystyle \binom{2}{2}~$ ways of selecting which two chocolates go to Person-C.
So, within the 2-2-2-1 distribution, once the $~\displaystyle \binom{7}{4}~$ factor is applied to determine which $~4~$ people get chocolates, the remaining factors are
$$\displaystyle 4 \times \binom{7}{1} \times \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{2}. \tag1 $$

The problem composer arrived at a math expression equivalent to the expression in (1) above, by a slightly different intellectual path:
They applied the factor of $~4~$ to identify which of the 4 people would only get one chocolate.  Then they (validly) decided that the person who only got one chocolate would get their chocolate last, among the 4 people, rather than first.
So the situation is:

You have Person-A, Person-B, Person-C, Person-D

Person-D, who gets his chocolate last, only gets 1 chocolate.  The other 3 people each get two chocolates.

You have Chocolate-1, ..., Chocolate-7.


There are $~\displaystyle \binom{7}{2}~$ ways of selecting which two chocolates go to Person-A.
Once that is done, there are then $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{2}~$ ways of selecting which two chocolates go to Person-B.
Once that is done, there are then $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{2}~$ ways of selecting which two chocolates go to Person-C.
Once that is done, there are then $~\displaystyle \binom{1}{1}~$ ways of selecting which two chocolates go to Person-D.
So, within the 2-2-2-1 distribution, once the $~\displaystyle \binom{7}{4}~$ factor is applied to determine which $~4~$ people get chocolates, the remaining factors are
$$\displaystyle 4 \times \binom{7}{2} \times \binom{5}{2} \times \binom{3}{2} \times \binom{1}{1}. \tag2 $$
The expression in (2) above is mathematically equivalent to the expression in (1) above.

The way I do it is to use for each valid distribution pattern, the format
[Lay Down Pattern] x [Permute pattern] which here would give
$4-1-1-1-0-0-0:\; \dfrac{7!}{4!}\cdot\dfrac{7!}{3!3!} = 29400$
$3-2-1-1-0-0-0:\; \dfrac{7!}{3!2!}\cdot\dfrac{7!}{2!3!} =176400$
$2-2-2-1-0-0-0:\: \dfrac{7!}{2!2!2!}\cdot\dfrac{7!}{3!3!}= 88200$
$Total\; \#\; of\; ways\; = \boxed{294000}$
This way I am very unlikely to make errors on the way

Added
You might understand better the computations written in full form. Taking the first distribution as an example, the full form would be
$\dfrac{7!}{4!1!1!1!0!0!0!}\cdot \dfrac{7!}{1!3!3!}$
but omitting the $1!s$ and $0!s$ won't change the answer, thus eliminated.
You may also note that the expressions are just one form of the multinomial coefficients,
$\dbinom{7}{4,1,1,1,0,0,0}\times \dbinom{7}{1,3,3}$

I am not able to understand how are you permuting the sequence, are you using the idea of permuting n distinct items into such that a objectsa are of one kind, b objects are of 2nd kind so on, then you can permute them in this manner : $\frac{n!}{a! * b! *.....}$

@VasuGupta: Yes, you can look at it that way. You should understand that the multinomial coefficient has three equivalent forms, eg $\dbinom{6}{2,2,1,1} \equiv \dbinom62\dbinom42\dbinom21\dbinom11 \equiv \dfrac{6!}{2!2!1!1!}$  The permutation form is the most compact because $1!$ and $0!$ can be weeded out.

@VasuGupta: You can have a look at an answer where I have used [Choose] x [Permute], and see how much more compact the current solution is. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569197/combinatorics-throwing-colored-dice/1569278#1569278

@VasuGupta: Or this one, where "of a kind" has been explicitly mentioned. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478458/how-many-ways-are-there-of-rolling-6-different-coloured-6-sided-dice-so-that-exa/1479324#1479324.
